# Можно ли в условии ON при İNNER JOİN использовать if/else?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть такая задача. В двух таблицах хранится информация о продукте. Общее поле - это `UrunID`. Есть еще два общих поля - депо и `Miktar`, но их значения не совпадают. И у каждого `UrunID` может быть несколько депо. Так вот, Нужно перенести общее количество товара по каждому айди во вторую таблицу(с минусом, потому что во трой таблице есть продажи (с минусом) и приход(с плюсом)), но записать в любой депо(кроме `AZ01` и `0`, там хранится приход) Следующий запрос переносит его во все депо, которые есть у UrunID (кроме `AZ01` и `0`)
Что я делаю не так? Разве `top 1` не подставляет всего один депо?

```
UPDATE A
SET [Miktar] = B.[Miktar]
FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_StokDurum] A INNER JOIN
 (SELECT DISTINCT [UrunID], Depo, SUM([Miktar]*-1) AS [Miktar]
  FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay]
  GROUP BY [UrunID], Depo) B
ON (A.UrunID = B.[UrunID] AND A.Depo = 
 (SELECT TOP 1 Depo 
  FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_StokDurum] 
  WHERE Depo != 'AZ01' AND Depo != '0'))
```

Первая таблица ([tb_SatisDetay])

```
Depo    SatisID UrunID  Barkod        Satici    KdvKod  KDVYuzde    Miktar  
AZ01    20001   3788898 8680367047775   999     AZ      18.00       1   
AZ01    20002   3788898 8680367047775   999     AZ      18.00       1   
AZ01    20003   3876390 8680367314891   999     AZ      18.00       1   
AZ01    20003   3793202 8680367070384   999     AZ      18.00       1   
AZ01    20003   4046508 8680367906676   999     AZ      18.00       1   
AZ01    20003   3843387 8680367191904   999     AZ      18.00       1   
AZ01    20003   3850608 8680367227726   999     AZ      18.00       1
```

Вторая таблица ([tb_StokDurum])

```
ID      UrunID  Depo    Miktar  Rezerve Ihrac   ReferansTabloNo MusteriEmanet
895871  2048780 0       0       0       0       NULL            0
895872  2048780 AZDD    -2      0       0       NULL            0
895878  2048780 AZ01    0       0       0       NULL            0
1201821 2426441 0       6       0       0       NULL            0
1201822 2426441 AZID    -16     0       0       NULL            0
1202304 2426441 AZ01    1       0       0       NULL            0
1201823 2454903 0       16      0       0       NULL            0
1201824 2454903 AZID    -25     0       0       NULL            0
1202273 2454903 AZ01    3       0       0       NULL            0
261207  4447996 0       0       0       0       NULL            0
261208  4447996 AZMR    -2      0       0       NULL            0
279066  4447996 AZ01    0       0       0       NULL            0
305244  4447996 AZ02    -2      0       0       NULL            0
```

Comment: У вас таблица "A" основная, вам надо условия на нее писать в WHERE, а не в ON. но при этом у вас подзапрос с top 1 выглядит как то не в кассу, вы получаете одно единственное Depo на весь остальной запрос. И что то мне подсказывает, что вы хотите получать его отдельно для каждого UrunID, потому как одного случайного Depo взятого по всей БД может и не быть у _каждого_ UrunID. В общем приведите примеры данных в таблицах (со структурой) и что на основе этих данных ожидаете получить

Comment: И кстати о каких if/else речь. что то я ничего подобного не вижу в запросе

Comment: @Mike Да, я изначально так и писала в WHERE, но результат такой же ( Да вы правы, я получаю сумму всех Miktar для каждого UrunID и во второй таблице хочу подставить в любой из Depo этого UrunID. Но у меня получается, что она попадает во все Depo этого UrunİD.

Comment: @Mike А if/else у меня к сожалению не получилось использовать  внутри условия ON. Но если есть такая возможность, то может это было бы как раз решением?

Answer (score 0):

Сложно сказать почему у вас апдейтились все Depo. Но есть явная проблема в том, что вы получали один единственный Depo в который писать для всей БД, а не для каждого UrunID. Кроме того в приведенном примере Depo проверялось в условиях соединения таблиц, но к соединению оно никакого отношения не имеет.

Следующий запрос должен решить вашу задачу:

```
UPDATE A
   SET [Miktar] = B.[Miktar]
  FROM tb_StokDurum A
  JOIN (
    SELECT C.[UrunID], -SUM(C.[Miktar]) AS [Miktar], min(D.Depo) Depo
      FROM tb_SatisDetay C
      JOIN (
            SELECT [UrunID], min(Depo) Depo FROM tb_StokDurum
             WHERE Depo not in('AZ01','0')
             group by [UrunID]
      ) D ON D.[UrunID]=C.[UrunID]
      GROUP BY C.[UrunID]
  ) B ON A.[UrunID]=B.[UrunID] and A.[Depo]=B.[Depo]
```

В нем Depo в которые писать получаются в правильном разрезе и внутри соединяемого подзапроса. Таким образом можно честно написать его в условиях соединения.

Comment: Вот это то что надо! Спасибо, но если честно, я не поняла что значит запись min(Depo) Depo и зачем она(не судите строго, я первый раз в SQL server пишу запрос, обычно в MySQL несложные запросы только нужно бывает), пойду погуглю ^_^

Comment: @Aziza  `min(Depo) Depo` аналогично `min(Depo) AS Depo` я просто привык AS опускать потому как он не обязателен. А min(Depo) с учетом group by UrunID дает минимальный Depo для группы, вам же все равно какой именно один Depo для группы будет использован, почему бы ему не быть минимальным